# Why do I get the anonymous type warning for this code?

Tags: c++, clang++, anonymous-types

When compiling my project I get the warning **anonymous types declared in an anonymous union are an extension [-Wnested-anon-types]**. My code contains this union:

```
union
{
    uint32_t m_bits;  // All bits
    struct
    {
      uint32_t significand : 23;
      uint32_t exponent : 8;
      uint32_t sign : 1;
    } IEEE;
  };
```

As far as other answers on the site have said, I would only expect this warning if I omitted the `IEEE`, name from the struct. But currently the struct should not be an anonymous type?

Comment: Because your struct type has no name?

Comment: @Chiel There is a difference between anonymous and unnamed structs. You are referring to the later.

Comment: @Rakete1111. You are correct. I did not know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the standard says so ([class.union.anon]):

> Note: Nested types, anonymous
>   unions, and functions cannot be declared within an anonymous union.

The wording of the warning could use some work, though. Clang allows (as a compiler extension) *unnamed* nested structs and additional anonymous unions within an anonymous union<sup>*</sup>, so it seems the author of the warning got just a little lazy and decided "anonymous types" was a good catch-all.

Note that giving your `union` a name (thus the union is no longer anonymous) makes the warning disappear.

<sup>*Named structs are still disallowed within anonymous unions (and there's no such thing as an anonymous struct)</sup>

Comment: So really the warning should say any types declared in an anonymous union are an extension?

Comment: @nitronoid: Yes that is my belief.

Comment: I see, how confusing. Thanks for the solution as well!

Comment: You can give a name to the struct so it will not be unonymous

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky the struct is currently unnamed but it is not anonymous.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky: The struct is *unnamed* not anonymous. Clang allows (as an extension) unnamed nested structs within an anonymous union. It will not allow a named struct declared within an anonymous union.